# Как указать замену изображения в заголовках записей при недостаточной ширине?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как указать в условии, чтобы в шапке страницы в сингл-постах при ширине изображения менее 1000px вместо post_thumbnail загружался header_image? А то юзеры могут постить маленькие фото, которые в шапке (при автоматическом увеличении) будут неважно смотреться.
Код такой (спасибо @KAGG Design и @Даниил):

```
    function oblique_header_style() {
    if ( get_header_image() && is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
                .site-header {
                    background: url(<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>) no-repeat;
                    background-position: center top;
                    background-attachment: fixed;
                    background-size: cover;
                }
    </style>
    <?php
    } 
    if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'oblique-single-thumb' );
    } else {
        $img = get_header_image();
    }
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .site-header {
            background: url(<?php echo $img; ?>) no-repeat;
            background-position: center top;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Стоит использовать `srcset`. По дефолту ВП его и использует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой код:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'oblique_header_style' ) ) :
    /**
     * Styles the header image and text displayed on the blog
     *
     * @see oblique_custom_header_setup().
     */
    function oblique_header_style() {
        global $post;

        $img = '';
        if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
            if ( 1000 <= $src[1] ) { // width
                $img = $src[0]; // url
            }
        }
        if ( '' === $img ) {
            $img = get_header_image();
        }
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .site-header {
                background: url(<?php echo $img; ?>) no-repeat;
                background-position: center top;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
endif; // oblique_header_style
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! :)